# Get source of image from li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a code like this

```
<ul class="dd-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/away.png"></span>1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/inacall.png"></span>2</a>
                </li><ul>
```

Javascript

```
menuApp = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#header-status'),
events: {
    'click .dd-menu li a': 'optionChange'
},
optionChange: function(e) {
    var selectedItemText = $(e.currentTarget).text();
    var selectedItemSrc = $(e.currentTarget).data("src"); 
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).data("src")); //Undefined
    $("#availability").text(selectedItemText);
    $("#availabilitySRC").attr("src").replace(selectedItemSrc); //Error
}});
```

I am trying to show selected li and now it shows text of selected li. However, It is not showing image of selected item. Is there a way to get src of img?

Thanks

Comment: I'd answered your previous question. You have a bad logic there. Navigation links should be used alongside with a router. Because when user refresh a page the active link will be lost.

Comment: Ohh that's right. I am new in coding and just try to implement it but I also understand your logic now. Thank you.

Comment: You can mark as `answered` your previous question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error while getting `src` is that you are referencing to a tag. You must reference to img tag. To do this:

```
optionChange: function(e) {
    var $a = $(e.currentTarget); // get a tag
    var $img = $a.find('img'); // find img in a tag
    var selectedItemText = $a.text(); // text from a
    var selectedItemSrc = $img.attr('src'); // src from img
    $("#availability").text(selectedItemText); // set text
    $("#availabilitySRC").attr('src', selectedItemSrc); // set src attr
}});
```

To get attribute from element use `attr('attribute-name')` function.
To change attribute value use `attr('attribute-name', newValue)`. `replace` if used to replace whole elements.

Comment: Actually it works (No error). Thank you. But when I print $img.attr('src') it gave /static/img/inacall.png (correct path) that I also expected but still there is no picture. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @waterkinq, check that element with id `availabilitySRC` exists in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your anchors have no `data-src` attribute and no `src` attribute(which is what I think you actually want to get), try selecting the image and getting its src attribute

```
optionChange: function(e) {
    var selectedItemText = $(e.currentTarget).text();
    var selectedItemSrc = $(this).find('img').attr("src"); 
    console.log(selectedItemSrc); 
    $("#availability").text(selectedItemText);
    $("#availabilitySRC").attr("src", selectedItemSrc); 
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/
https://api.jquery.com/attr/